# How to run all unit-tests from a test jar?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, junit

I ran the following command to produce a test-jar: `mvn jar:test-jar`.

What's the `mvn` command to execute all unit-tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're creating a jar containing test-classes, you would probably want to reuse those classes. For example, some common test fixtures or abstract base classes, and so on.

In other words, when you run `mvn jar:test-jar`, you create new artifact, which you can add as dependency in other maven project or module:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <classifier>tests</classifier> <!-- note the classifier -->
      <type>test-jar</type> <!-- note the type -->
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**Note:** that such approach is not the preferred way, since [`test-jar` will loose transitive `test-scoped` dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)

So, returning to the original question: you don't create `test-jar` to run tests, you create it to reuse test classes between projects or modules (by means of adding `dependency`).

To run tests you'll simply use standard Maven command:

```
mvn clean test
```